# SSR Component for Date Picking?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks

I am trying to build a landing page that has a date picker in it and after the user has selected it they can click a button that will redirect them to a page. I am using NextJS and the parent component called Landing is SSR as I would like it to be good enough for SEO. But looking at date pickers for react it seems all have to be rendered at the client. I am using react-modern-calendar-date-picker and the way to set the selected date is using state unless it can be done some other way. As such it must be a client rendered component but I was wondering if it can done some other way.

```
const DynamicDatePicker = dynamic(() => import('react-modern-calendar-date-picker'), { ssr: false });
```

I see this imports at the client but what is the point if I cannot use this due to the state. Any ideas? My approach is to create the entire component as a client side component but again it does not seem as the best solution with SEO in mind.

Comment: Do SEO details include date selected by client ?
Are you using App Router or Pages Router ?

Comment: I am using the app router. What do you mean by SEO details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :**

> I am trying to build a landing page that has a date picker in it and a**fter the user has selected** it they can **click a button** that will redirect them to a page. I am using NextJS and the parent component called Landing is SSR as I would like it to be good enough for SEO.....

**Solution :**
As per NextJS docs, Client Components are components which have Interactivity(onChange(), onClick() etc) or they are dependedent on browser APIs.

- As your component is using state & it has interacitivity then you should keep it as Client component.

Regarding SEO, you need to add SEO related details/data(title,description,tags etc. its called `metatags` and this tags related data is `Metadata`its responsible for SEO) in the `page.js`. While page contains Client-side components you can still generate its metadata.

*To generate metadata read the [1](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata)st  link given below.*

**Example :**

```
export const metadata = 
{
  title: 'Homepage',
  description: 'Description of this page',
}
     
export default function Page() {
    return (
    <>
       <ClientComponent/>
       <OtherComponents/>
    </>
    
    )
}
```

Now when this above page is rendered, SEO related details are there.
*(there are many tags involved in making a page SEO friendly please read about them)*

**Please Read :**

1. **Metadata** : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata
2. **Client Components :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components
3. **Server and Client Composition Patterns :**  https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns
4. **Search Engine Optimization :** https://nextjs.org/learn-pages-router/seo/introduction-to-seo

Comment: I have it as a client component and created an skeleton to sort of give it a faster feeling thank you for the links I will go over them as I go. I am wondering  since the child csr rendered component calls the next page (which again will be a mix of server and client components) if there will be an issue when it comes to google crawling the page. I mean, will the bots reach that page and subsequent pages or will they do it on the second pass when js is executed?